# Building charts in Flex Builder Professional

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I have Flex Builder Professional Ver 3 (Built with Eclipse) version.

I need to build an application with charts. The problem is that there are no charting components to be seen. There is no datavisualization.swc file in the libs folder.

What could be the problem? Any ideas?

Regards,
Vinayak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason was that the charts are included only in the Adobe Flexbuilder program - and not in the Eclipse version.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Axiis Data Visualization Framework](http://www.axiis.org/examples.html/) could be useful

Comment: Hey this is very helpful. A useful resource. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the instalation the installer asks you if you want to add the data visualization components , I think it is priced differently also.

Comment: From the Adobe website and help documentation, I understand that charting is available in both versions - Standard and Professional. In the standard version, there is a watermark on the charts. However, I am using the Professional version - but the charts are completely missing. :-(